# android sqlite where value can be any value

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a function which takes in a month and year parameter and returns all values from the DB where month and year match, now I need to make a query to the db where year matches a variable but month can be any month, i want to use the same function rather than create a new function, so with what values do I call this function.

Current call looks like this

```
            ArrayList<PaymentHistory> allPayment = dataSource.findfiltered("Transactions", yearToGet, monthToGet);
```

and then function looks like this

```
public ArrayList<PaymentHistory> findfiltered(String dbName, String year,  String month){
    //this needs to be done still
    String whereClause = DBOpenHelper.YEAR + " = ? AND "+ DBOpenHelper.STATUS + " = ? AND "  + DBOpenHelper.MONTH + " = ?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
            year,
            "paid",  //we only want successful transactions
            month
    };
    Cursor cursor = database.query(dbName, allColumns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);  //must sort this

    ArrayList<PaymentHistory> paymentHistories = getListDatas(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return paymentHistories;
}
```

Comment: You need to do some changes in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes in your method.

```
public ArrayList<PaymentHistory> findfiltered(String dbName, String year,  String month){
        //this needs to be done still
        String whereClause = DBOpenHelper.YEAR + " = ? AND "+ DBOpenHelper.STATUS + " = ? AND "  + DBOpenHelper.MONTH + " = ?";
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
                year,
                "paid", //we only want successful transactions
                month
        };
        if(month == null) {
                whereClause = DBOpenHelper.YEAR + " = ? AND "+ DBOpenHelper.STATUS + " = ?";
                String[] whereArgs = new String[] {
                        year,
                        "paid"                        
                };
        }


        Cursor cursor = database.query(dbName, allColumns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null); //must sort this

        ArrayList<PaymentHistory> paymentHistories = getListDatas(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return paymentHistories;
}
```

Now when you need to get result regardless of the month, just pass a null at month's place.

```
ArrayList<PaymentHistory> allPayment = dataSource.findfiltered("Transactions", yearToGet, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

If need filter by month, call

```
 ArrayList<PaymentHistory> allPayment = dataSource.findfiltered("Transactions", yearToGet, monthToGet);
```

If do not need filter by month, call

```
 ArrayList<PaymentHistory> allPayment = dataSource.findfiltered("Transactions", yearToGet, "");
```

Method:

```
public ArrayList<PaymentHistory> findfiltered(String dbName, String year,  String month){
    //this needs to be done still

    String whereClause = DBOpenHelper.YEAR + " = ? AND "+ DBOpenHelper.STATUS + " = ?";
    Cursor cursor = null;
    if(month != "")
    {
        whereClause +=" AND "  + DBOpenHelper.MONTH + " = ?";
        cursor = database.query(dbName, allColumns, whereClause, new String[] {year,"paid",month}, null, null, null);  //must sort this
    }
    else{
        cursor = database.query(dbName, allColumns, whereClause, new String[] {year,"paid"}, null, null, null);  //must sort this
    }

    ArrayList<PaymentHistory> paymentHistories = getListDatas(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return paymentHistories;
}
```